# Red neuronal para progremas de regresión en Matlab

Tags: matlab, redes-neuronales, machine-learning, regresión-lineal

¡Hola!

Estoy intentando implementar mi primera red neuronal en MATLAB siguiendo el ejemplo de la figura 5.3 (página 231) de '[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf)', de C. Bishop.

Este ejemplo usa una red neuronal de dos 'layers' (¿capas?) para implementar varias transformaciones, como la función seno, cuadrado, valor absoluto o escalón. De este modo, tanto la entrada como la salida tienen un solo nodo, mientras que la 'hidden layer' (¿cómo se traduce?) tiene 3. He utilizado la función **tanh** como función de activación, mientras que la salida es lineal.

La única función que a veces se """parece""" (cuando veáis la foto entenderéis lo que quiero decir con tantas comillas) es la función seno. El resto directamente son un despropósito. ¿No debería la solución funcionar para todos los casos como en el ejemplo?

Os adjunto mi código (que es una versión modificada de otro que he encontrado y una foto de lo que sale [aquí](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/55826-pattern-recognition-and-machine-learning-toolbox)) y la imagen que os comenté antes. ¡Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda!

```
%% INITIALIZATION
h = [3];
X = linspace(-1,1,1000);
T = sin(X*pi);

%% NEURAL NETWORK
eta = 1/size(X,2);
h = [size(X,1);h(:);size(T,1)];
L = numel(h);
W = cell(L-1,1);
for l = 1:L-1
    W{l} = randn(h(l),h(l+1)); % Should I maybe initialize this differently?
end
Z = cell(L,1);
Z{1} = X;
maxiter = 10000;
mse = zeros(1,maxiter);
%     forward
for iter = 1:maxiter
    for l = 2:L-1
        Z{l} = tanh(W{l-1}'*Z{l-1});   % 5.10, 5.49
    end
    Z{L} = W{L-1}'*Z{L-1}; % Linear output activation function
%     backward
    E = T-Z{L}; % E = dk       
    mse(iter) =  mean(dot(E,E),1);
    dW = Z{L-1}*E';
    W{L-1} = W{L-1}+eta*dW;
    for l = L-2:-1:1
        df = 1-Z{l+1}.^2;    % Derivative of tanh function
        dj = df.*(W{l+1}*E);
        dW = Z{l}*dj';    % 5.67
        W{l} = W{l}+eta*dW;
        E = dj;
    end
end
mse = mse(1:maxiter);
model.W = W;

%% RESULTS
plot(mse);
disp(['T = [' num2str(T) ']']);
W = model.W;
Y = X;
for l = 1:length(W)-1
    Y = tanh(W{l}'*Y);
end
Y = W{length(W)}'*Y;
disp(['Y = [' num2str(Y) ']']);

figure
plot(X, T, 'o');
hold on
plot(X, Y);
legend('T (target output)','Y (trained output)', 'Location', 'southeast');
hold off
```

### [image: Target output versus trained output] [image: Variation of error with the number of iterations]